# Tree identification from dried branch

Tags: species-identification, trees

I found a very interesting branch last week, and have been trying to identify it but cannot seem to find the answer. If anyone has any suggestion, I would be grateful.

I found it near the forest, around WA area.

Here's some picture:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I just reviewed an edit which seemed to be updating the original answer, but was not by the original poster. If it is actually the same person, I would recommend you [recover your password](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password)

Answer (score 5):

This looks like dried [cholla cactus](http://www.desertusa.com/mag99/may/papr/chollas.html), although it will be hard to determine the species. It is sold commonly for fishtanks, so might even be found in places where it does not grow naturally if someone cleaned out their fish tank.

[image]

EDIT by Ilan: on this image you can clearly see that the tree identified right:

[image]